# how do i allow html tags in php input field?

Tags: php, html, input, tags

I have an `<input/>` field (see below) in my PHP file.

I wish to use some HTML tags in it's value. If I add a HTML tag like `<br>`, it does nothing. when I add the `<br>` tag it just shows as text.

So I wonder how I can make my `<input/>` field to allow HTML tags and of course not show up as text on page?

```
<input type="text" name="i18n[<?php echo $v['id']; ?>][name]" class="pj-form-field w300" value="<?php echo pjSanitize::html(@$tpl['calendar_arr']['i18n'][$v['id']]['name']); ?>" />
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how you can format the text inside an input? Or are you asking how you can allow people to type HTML source code into the input?

Comment: sorry for bad explanation.

yes i want user to able to use html tags in input fields. as it is now when typing a html tag nothing happens it just show html tag as text.

Comment: **What** "just show html tag as text"? Do you mean that if the user types a `<` then a `<` shows up in the input, immediately? Or are you talking about what happens after the form is submitted?

Comment: Hi,
sorry for bad explanation :(

admin type this is in to a input box in administration for a property:: central town < br > Manhattan.
but the br is not working so the result on website shows the br html tag. i wanted it to result to like like this:

central town 
Manhattan

so the code i added before is the php code for that input field so i thought that will help to show the code and if i can add something to the code to make html tags work,

Comment: Normally just adding a soft return (shift enter) in the input field will give you a `<br>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can look into `contenteditable` attribute of `HTML`

```
<div contenteditable="true">Styled <span style="color:green;">input goes</span> <b>here</b></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scjnwrnf/32/